# How can I sort table data date field according months

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have row date inside the table and I applied bootstrap datatable sorting its working fine but i want to sort that date according months like i have 1Jan,2feb,3march
but if the date is in table 1march,2feb,3jan so i want like that 3jan,2feb,1march number does not matter months will be always jan will comes first and feb second and so on....

```
$('#sortpaid_id').DataTable( {
    columnDefs: [
        { type: 'date-eu', targets: 0 }
    ]
});
```

This is my javascript code which I added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "date-eu-pre": function ( date ) {
    date = date.replace(" ", "");

    if ( ! date ) {
      return 0;
    }

    var year;
    var eu_date = date.split(/[\.\-\/]/);

    /*year (optional)*/
    if ( eu_date[2] ) {
      year = eu_date[2];
    }
    else {
      year = 0;
    }

    /*month*/
    var month = eu_date[1];
    if ( month.length == 1 ) {
      month = 0+month;
    }

    /*day*/
    var day = eu_date[0];
    if ( day.length == 1 ) {
      day = 0+day;
    }

    return (year + month + day) * 1;
  },

  "date-eu-asc": function ( a, b ) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
  },

  "date-eu-desc": function ( a, b ) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
  }
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Not clear what data looks like or what sort order should be. Please provide a [mcve] as well as expected results

Comment: Hi charlietfl, I have row in table which having date field, currently datatable sort that date according to date like 1jan,2 feb, 3 mar, and descending too but i want to sort according months like number would be anything but the month would be like jan,feb, march and so on.. and the descending order is dec,nove,oct and so on.. no matter date numbers 1,2 or 3 i hope you got  my point